# Change response in terminate function of middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to change the message from 500 errors if certain conditions are met. I have this middleware in a file called ApiAfter.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Helpers\Helper;
use App\Helpers\LogHelper;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Closure;
use DateTime;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class ApiAfter
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response) {
        // move everything in handle function to this
        // logging the results of the request
        $response = $this->fixFiveHundred($request, $response);

        // I do some other stuff here

        return $response;
    }

    private function fixFiveHundred($request, $response) {
        if ($response->status() !== 500) return $response;

        try {
            if (!empty($response->original['message']) && $response->original['message'] === "Server Error") {
                if (!empty($response->exception)) {
                    $newMessage = $response->exception->getMessage();
                    return response($newMessage, 500); // this is the line of code I'm having trouble with
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

On the line that says `return response($newMessage, 500);`, I've tried lots of different things but nothing is actually changing the response. Can you not change a response in the Terminate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid handling exception in a custom middleware. Laravel provides a simple class that allows simple customization. Have a look to "render method" of [Laravel Error Handling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#render-method) in official docs.

Answer (score 1):

`Can you not change a response in the Terminate function?`

Short answer: No.

The terminate function in a [middleware runs after the response was sent to the browser](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#terminable-middleware). Thus, you can't modify the response.

As @Roberto Ferro pointed, the right place to handle custom response for exceptions is using the render in the [Exception Handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors)